# Client authentication flaw in old Netscape SSL protocol

Tags: tls, authentication, client

Below is a screenshot from the paper "Prudent Engineering Practice for Cryptographic Protocols" by Martin Abadi and Roger Needham. I can't see what's wrong with the protocol and what the fix achieves. Help please? It's driving me crazy.

[image: Example 3.4 in Prudent Engineering Practice for Cryptographic Protocols]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *C* be the attacker. *C* runs another server, under its own name (*C*), with its own public key *K<sub>c</sub>*. Occasionally, *A* connects to *C* (knowingly, but not knowing that *C* is Evil, or believing that the evilness of *C* won't extend beyond *C* itself). Attack goes thus:

- Client *A* connects to *C* and sends *{K<sub>ac</sub>}<sub>K<sub>c</sub></sub>* to *C*.
- Immediately, *C* connects to server *B* and claims to be *A*. *C* generates a random *K<sub>cb</sub>* and sends *{K<sub>cb</sub>}<sub>K<sub>b</sub></sub>* to *B*.
- *B* responds to *C* with *{N<sub>b</sub>}<sub>K<sub>cb</sub></sub>* to *C*. Since *C* knows *K<sub>cb</sub>*, *C* can decrypt that and obtains *N<sub>b</sub>*.
- *A* is still waiting. *C* sends to *A* the value *{N<sub>b</sub>}<sub>K<sub>ac</sub></sub>*. That's the tricky point: *C* sends to *A* as challenge the same value as the one sent by *B* to *C*.
- *A* responds with *{CA, {N<sub>b</sub>}<sub>K<sub>a</sub><sup>-1</sup></sub>}<sub>K<sub>ac</sub></sub>*, as per the protocol. Since *C* knows *K<sub>ac</sub>*, *C* can decrypt that.
- *C* sends *{CA, {N<sub>b</sub>}<sub>K<sub>a</sub><sup>-1</sup></sub>}<sub>K<sub>cb</sub></sub>* to *B*.

And, voila! *C* has successfully executed the protocol with *B*, sending a proper certificate and signature from *A*, computed over the challenge value that *B* sent to *C*. *C* is thus authenticated as *A* with regards to server *B*. The genuine *A* noticed nothing, and is not aware that anything was done related to server *B* at all.

The correction described in the article fixes the issue, which is that in the original protocol, the signature from *A* is retargetable: in the attack, *A* signs a challenge received from server *C*, but the signature also works as a response for the same challenge from server *B*. Including *B*'s name in what is signed prevents the manipulation: now, a response to a challenge from a given server cannot be used as response to the same challenge from another, distinct server.

There are other similar attacks which also force the inclusion of *A*'s name in what is signed. In [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) as it is currently defined, the signature from the client (in the `ClientKeyExchange` message) is computed over a hash of *all previous handshake messages* (sent and received), which includes both the client and server names (as part of their respective `Certificate` messages).